# SwitchMap on hot observables first emission

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I've a method returning a HOT `Observable<Integer>`. Upon subscription a value is emitted and then a stream of other `Integers` will come (eventually).

I've 10 of these `Observable<Integer>` (different instances). and what I'd like to do, written in english is:

- if all of these `10` Observable emit `0` as first `Integer`
- then mergeWith a `Fallback set of observable`

The reason behind this logic is that, I'd like to check a portion of my db (first 10 Observable) and if the db contains data, then stick with the first set of 10 Observable. But, if the db currently contains no data(Integer 0) at those positions, then use a "section of the db" that is suppoused to contain data.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first element (with `take(1)`) and filter `0` from each observable, then count the number of items (using `count()`).

The "tricky" part is that your observabable are hot. You'll have to enshure that you're not missing the first element.

```
    Observable.just(obs1, ob2, ..., obs10)
              .flatMap(obs -> obs.take(1).filter(i -> i == 0))
              .count()
              .filter(count -> count == 10)
              .isEmpty()
              .flatMap(isEmpty -> {
                        if(isEmpty) {
                            return Observable.empty();
                        } else {
                            return fallbackObservable();
                        }
              }).subscribe();
```